# Cannot load XMLHttpRequest on the same machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to load a simple txt-file from my local machine with jQuery.

When doing:

```
$.ajax({
    method : "GET",
    url : "folder/file.txt",
    dataType : 'text',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///home/user/path/to/file/data/file.txt. Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

But how is this possible, when both files (the JavaScript and the txt) are in the same directory on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome considers all XMLHttpRequest requests to `file:` URIs to be cross-origin.

If you want to use XMLHttpRequest, then run an HTTP server.

Comment: So for example XAMPP?

Comment: @user1170330 — Well, that would be a Apache HTTP bundled with a bunch of other stuff, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a quick test you are performing, then a quick solution would be to use a different browser. For instance, Firefox runs that piece of code just fine.